# How to get access to JSON data with dash in name in Angular2?

Tags: json, node.js, angular

I need to get access to JSON data which names contain dash, what is best solution? To remove dash or just handle that 
This is my JSON data which I recive from simple node server.

```
[{
"id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"type": "container",
"path": "/",
"dctitle": "xxxx",
"dc-creator": "xxxx",
"dc-description": "xxxx.",
"dcrights": "xxxx",
"hero-region": {
    "hero-headline": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "hero-headline-sub": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `console.log(data[0]["hero-region"]["hero-headline"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, you should not use dashes in json keys. This evaluates to subtraction:

```
dc - creator
```

I've generally seen the `-` replaced with and `_` or converted to camelCase.

It looks like you can cmd-shift-L to replace all of the dashes in vsCode or and you can ten replace with the underscore. Be careful that dashes don't exist in you data though.

To convert to camelCase easily you can use this powerful extension: [MD Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=seanmcbreen.MDTools)

if you insist then you can access a key that contains characters that cannot appear in an identifier, using brackets:

```
["dc-creator"]
```